# Google Script, Import HTML data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a personal notifier whenever a certain website contains the word 'Indian' the script should email me.
For some reason I cannot find a script function that would import HTML data,

Is there such a function?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can perform a URL fetch:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String)

Answer (score 0):

Just like [Harold said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22295407/10871073), you can perform a URL fetch:

```
var output = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/####");
var form = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(output.getContentText());
SpreadsheetApp.getUI().showModalDialog(form, "Fetched HTML");
```

You can otherwise fetch a website using the same tactic, for example:

```
var output = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.google.com");
var form = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(output.getContentText());
SpreadsheetApp.getUI().showModalDialog(form, "Fetched HTML");
```

Upon launch, the dialog should return Google's homepage.